# Importing variables from config.py files - what is happening under the hood?

Tags: python, import, namespaces, config

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to wrap my head around how a "config.py" module can help share variables across other modules in a Package. I've Googled for a while and have read several articles on python.org and elsewhere about various flavors of imports, and I've learned a lot about how imports work under the hood, and I think maybe I mostly have it but I still have a lingering question in terms of how `from...import` works when a `__init__.py` file is implicitly involved.

For example, say I have this simple package setup with simple modules (each module's simple code lines are put underneath each module for easier readability here):

```
    test/
       __init__.py
          from test import config
          config.username = "username-init"

       config.py
          username = "username-config"

       mainthing.py
          from test import config
          print(config.username)
```

I can then open Python and run this:

```
import mainthing
'username-init'  # it auto-prints "username-init" per the last line in mainthing.py
```

My question is around how `mainthing.py` gets the value of of the `config.username` variable that was edited by the `__init__.py` module. In my mind, here is the flow of operations when I run `import mainthing` in Python:

1. `mainthing.py`

   - `from test import config`

     - because we're saying `from test`, the `__init__.py` file in the `test` package runs first.
2. `__init__.py`

   - `from test import config`

     - This imports `config.py` into the namespace of `__init__.py`
   - `config.username = "username-init"

     - inside the namespace of `__init__.py`, we give the `config.username` variable a value of "username-init"
3. `mainthing.py`

   - still on the `from test import config` line, we have just ran `__init__.py` and now we can proceed with importing the `config.py` module from the `test` package into the namespace of `mainthing.py`
   - `print(config.username)`

     - This prints "username-init", so the value that was set in the namespace of `__init__.py`.

       - I guess this is where my question lies (apologies for the confusing novel that follows). When `mainthing.py` imports any module, it of course imports variables and functions from that module being imported (accessibility depends on how it was imported of course). But in the case of using a `config.py` file, when I use `from test` in my `mainthing.py` file and then `__init__.py` implicitly runs as part of that line of code, I'm then importing into `mainthing.py` the namespace of `__init__.py` which would itself contain its own `config.username` variable inside its own `__init__.py` namespace. Assuming this is correct, what then happens in `mainthing.py` when Python then encounters the `import config` part of the line `from test import config`, seeing that the `from test` part in `mainthing.py` has already run? Would it see that `config` was already implicitly loaded in the namespace of `__init__.py` in the first part of the `from...import` command (`from test`) and that it doesn't need to be loaded into `mainthing.py` again ? If so, `mainthing.py` would get the `config.username` value that was in the namespace of `__init__.py` ("username-init") and not in the namespace of `config.py` ("username-config"). As you can see I'm a bit mixed up on how it actually works. Again, I've read a lot of official and non-official documentation but I'm still a bit fuzzy on what is actually happening under the hood. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `config.username` is not a single variable. `config` is a module, and `username` is an attribute of the module (and a global variable in the module's namespace). No matter who imports `config`, they get access to the same `username` attribute of that module.

Comment: True, but I guess I'm calling config.username a variable the same way I call C:\temp\file.txt a file, I'm just adding the full path for clarity. Here, my question is around how from...import works when a config.py and __init__.py file are involved and __init__.py changes the config modue that your main module is already importing.

Comment: `test/__init__.py` just defines the module `test` (which, as a package, also contains the modules `config` and `mainthing`. (It's just the convention Python uses instead of having `test.py` along side `test/`.)

Comment: ah ok cool, so `__init__.py` is essentially the same thing as `[package name].py`. Like `test/__init__.py` is used instead of `test/test.py` ?

Comment: Basically. (`test/test.py` would be a module in a package of the same name; I'm not sure of the reasoning for choosing or preferring `./test/__init__.py` over `./test.py` along side `./test`.)